# How to run Laravel 8 on MAMP?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, laravel-5, mamp

I have this in my `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8",
    "alkhachatryan/laravel-web-console": "^3.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^8",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~6.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1"
},
```

I'm trying to run my Laravel app via MAMP v6.6

I kept getting

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.8. in /Users/laravel-app/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

macOS 12.3

**php --version**

> PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2022 10:46:35) (NTS)
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.1.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.1.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologie

Comment: To be honest, MAMP is not the best option for a local Laravel installation. It's quite slow. There are better options like Docker, Valet, ... . I use Valet 3 so i can isolate the php version per project with one command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that you have 2 versions of PHP installed on that Mac -- one is a web server, and one is a command line. Take your MAMP web server, and create a page that has nothing but `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Then, visit that web page and it will give you a long list of information including the version of PHP. Usually you want to have the command line version and the web server version to be in sync, but that's your perogative.

Comment: My new macbook shipped with PHP 8.1.8. but my MAMP have only 8.0.8 max. What do I do?

Comment: Let me try download the latest MAMP again now !